# query privacy setting on profile interests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

I'm writing an app to help users understand their Facebook privacy settings.  I know how to access the privacy settings for a specific video, note, link, photo, or photo album.  However, I want to determine the user's privacy settings for their extended profile information, such as favorite books, movies etc.

Is there a table to access this kind of privacy information?

Related:
  Without the user_likes permission, I can only access favorite movies if their audience selector is set to public.  With user_likes, I can access favorite movies no matter what the setting.  However, I also want to determine the state of the audience selector for favorite moves, not just access their favorite movies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Facebook does not expose user privacy settings via the public API.  If your company simply cannot live without it, then you should have your business development team contact facebook to see if an agreement can be reached.  It'll probably cost lots of time and money to pursue it with Facebook.